# Type order with overloaded methods in Java

Tags: java, types

Given two methods on the same class in Java :

```
public void doSomething( Person person );
public void doSomething( Employee employee );
```

where

```
Employee extends Person
```

If I call:

```
doSomething( employee )
```

I find that `doSomething( Person )` gets invoked.

I'd have expected the overload with the closest matching contract be invoked, not with the most abstract (which is what I'm finding)

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most specific applicable overload is used - but that overload is determined at *compile*-time, based on the compile time type of the `employee` variable.

In other words:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
doSomething(employee); // Calls doSomething(Employee)
```

but:

```
Person employee = new Employee();
doSomething(employee); // Calls doSomething(Person)
```

Note that this is unlike *overriding* where it's the *execution time* type of the target object which is important.

Comment: Boy your quick Jon, second time you've beet me to the answer today :)

Comment: No fair, I beat both of you (although I must admit my first version wasn't extremely helpful).

Comment: The way Jon answers is like reading a reference manual--complete, concise, to the point.

Man this guy pisses me off.  :)

Answer (score 3):

How was `employee` declared? If it was declared as `Person employee = new Employee();`, then `doSomething(Person)` is indeed the closest matching overload.

Unlike overrides, overloads are determined at compile time. Therefore, even though the runtime type of `employee` is `Employee`, the `Person` overload has already been chosen to be executed.

See the [JLS §8.4.9 Overloading](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.9):

> When a method is invoked [(§15.12)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#20448), the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked [(§15.12.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#292575). If the method that is to be invoked is an instance method, the actual method to be invoked will be determined at run time, using dynamic method lookup [(§15.12.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#45677).

Answer (score 1):

The method selection is done at compile time not run time, so if you had

```
Person employee = new Employee();
doSomething(employee);
```

This would call doSomething(Person) as the declared type is Person, regardless of the fact the instance is also a Employee.

Answer (score 0):

On calling an overloaded, the method with the closest matching signature will be called. I suspect your `employee` is a `Person` variable. So at the method call, the reference type of `employee` causes your `doSomething(Person person)` to get selected.